# What is the best way to handle a slideout menu in winui 3

Tags: windows, xaml, winui-3

There's not a lot of information about this that is easily findable. I don't doubt it's extremely basic but all the more reason to share the knowledge around.

I want to have a small panel on the left hand side of the screen, and when the mouse hovers over it, I want it to slide out horizontally. Think the x when you enter full screen mode on chrome but rotated.

What is the best and most proper way of achieving this?

And as part of it, what should be used instead of a stack panel etc, to allow for mouse over and hover events to cover an area of multiple buttons?

Comment: for mouse , you can use pointerEntered/Exited events and for showing panel you can use VisualStates i think.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `SplitView` control:

```xml
<SplitView
    x:Name="SplitViewControl"
    DisplayMode="Inline">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <TextBlock Text="Pane" />
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <StackPanel>
        <FontIcon
            x:Name="OpenPaneIcon"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Glyph="&#xEA5B;"
            PointerEntered="OpenPaneIcon_PointerEntered" />
        <TextBlock Text="Open" />
    </StackPanel>
</SplitView>
```

and when the pointer enters the `FontIcon`, you can open the pane in the code-behind:

```cs
private void OpenPaneIcon_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SplitViewControl.IsPaneOpen = true;
}
```